# SQLite Text Charset

Tags: java, string, sqlite, character-encoding

I've been trying to make queries into an SQLite database using Java and can't seem to convert the string to the correct charset (if its not already in the correct one)

My query string is:

`'%00.interesting files collection 2/B4U(BEMANI FOR YOU MIX) c¦ºi¦üENOTHER/B4U(BEMANI FOR YOU MIX)%'`

however the database has encoded the string as:

`/Songs/00.interesting files collection 2/B4U(BEMANI FOR YOU MIX) c��i��ENOTHER/B4U(BEMANI FOR YOU MIX).sm`

Difference there is: `��` is used over `¦ºi¦ü`

I am not sure what Charset I should be using to encode the string in order to get it to satisfy what the DB has. I can think of one solution (assuming it works) though its a bit crude, converting the String to `US-ASCII` then replacing all `?` with `�`.

Comment: Well, the SQLite database is using either UTF-8 or UTF-16. Find out which one, and use that.

Comment: I've gotten the encoding right now however it seems that it cannot say that the `�` from my input string is the same as the `�` stored in the column.